# How to make a simple HTML playlist using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, audio, playlist

I need some help making a very simple Jquery playlist using audio html tag. So far I got his:

```
<audio id="myAudio" preload="auto">
  Your user agent does not support the HTML5 Audio element.
</audio>
```

and the jquery part:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
  bgAudio = document.getElementById("myAudio");
  bgAudio.volume = 0.3;

  bgAudio.controls = true;
  bgAudio.loop = true;
  bgAudio.autoplay = true;

  bgAudio.src = "bg1.mp3";
  bgAudio.src = "bg2.mp3";
  bgAudio.play();

});
</script>
```

How can I make those 2 mp3's play one after another? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- There was no element to use the `animate` to so I made a `div#bg` and wrapped it around the audio element. Remember, if you want to make an element fade in with opacity, make sure the element starts off with `opacity:0`
- The expression should be: `$('div#bg').animate({opacity: 1}, 1000);`
- I took a look at your question... it doesn't have that `animate()` anymore?
- The playlist is in an array.
- The function `player()` is called upon `document ready` (So you don't need `autoplay` that mobile devices ignore anyways)
- The player will play each audio clip in succession and upon completing the playlist it starts over again (`loop` only works on one file, not on a playlist. So you'd never progress to the next file if `loop=true`)

**Snippet**

```css
MNG- https://vocaroo.com/media_command.php?media=s0Ai9tr7779v&command=download_mp3
Righteous- https://vocaroo.com/media_command.php?media=s1dKHkbev0dJ&command=download_mp3
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>35478017</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='bg' style="opacity:0">
    <audio id="xAudio" preload="auto"></audio>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    
    // This is a simple array of strings
    var playlist = [
      "https://vocaroo.com/media_command.php?media=s1H9fX5GI9Fa&command=download_mp3",
      "https://vocaroo.com/media_command.php?media=s0Ai9tr7779v&command=download_mp3",
      "https://vocaroo.com/media_command.php?media=s1dKHkbev0dJ&command=download_mp3"
    ];
    
    // Remember that element must start out at opacity:0
    // The duration should be only a number outside of the curly brackets
    $('div#bg').animate({
      opacity: 1
    }, 1000);


    $(document).ready(function() {
      var xA = document.getElementById("xAudio");
      xA.volume = 0.3;
      xA.controls = true;


      function player(x) {
        var i = 0;
        xA.src = playlist[x]; // x is the index number of the playlist array 
        xA.load();            // use the load method when changing src
        xA.play();
        xA.onended = function() { // Once the initial file is played it plays the rest of the files
          /* This would be better as a 'for' loop */
          i++;                   
          if (i > 2) {            //         ... Repeat
            i = 0;                //         ^
          }                       //         ^
          xA.src = playlist[i];   // Rinse,  ^
          xA.load();              // Lather, ^
          xA.play();              // and.....^
        }
      }
      player(0); // Call the player() function at 0 index of playlist array
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The animation was for another component, not the player. I removed it when I saw I added it by mistake.

Comment: Well it actually adds a nice touch IMO.

Comment: Your code works superb man. Thanks a ton! This is the final result: http://www.tzr.ro

Comment: Great, anytime, sir. :-)

Comment: That's very elegant.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use the [audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API) to bind an `onended` event on to `bgAudio` and switch the source there.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var bgAudio = document.getElementById("myAudio");
  var src1 = "bg1.mp3";
  var src2 = "bg2.mp3";

  bgAudio.volume = 0.3;

  bgAudio.controls = true;
  bgAudio.loop = false;
  bgAudio.autoplay = true;
  bgAudio.src = src1;

  bgAudio.onended = function(){
    bgAudio.stop();
    bgAudio.src = src2;
    bgAudio.play();
  }

  bgAudio.play();

});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wpwddq30/

NOTE: This is untested, just to give an idea of the events

Answer (score 0):

I did improve the answer a bit, so the initial song will start random and just be followed chronologically by the rest.

```
<script>

    var playlist = [
        "music/bg1.mp3",
        "music/bg2.mp3",
        "music/bg3.mp3",
        "music/bg4.mp3"
    ];

    var n = playlist.length-1;
    var r = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * n);

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var xA = document.getElementById("myAudio");
        xA.volume = 0.3;
        xA.controls = true;

        function player(x) {
            var i = 0;

            xA.src = playlist[r];
            xA.load();
            xA.play();
            xA.onended = function() {
                i++;
                if (i > n) {
                    i = 0;
                }

                xA.src = playlist[i];
                xA.load();
                xA.play();
            }
        }
        player(0);
    });
    </script>
```

I was thinking of making all songs repeat in a shuffle way, but I believe I would need to do an array of numbers to count them down or something. Still. it's just optional!